# add together the numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a txt file with numbers between space in a few lines and I want to add together the numbers in each line and write the amount to the line's end. I split the file by newlines, it's okay, but I don't know how can I add together the numbers.

```
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    RandomAccessFile raf= new RandomAccessFile("numbers.txt","rw");
    while (raf.getFilePointer() < raf.length()) {
        String sor = raf.readLine();

        String newline[] = sor.split("\r\n");
        for (String item:newline) {
            numbers.add(item);
        }

    }
    // just test
    for(String item:numbers)
        System.out.println(item);

    raf.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("An error was occured: "+ e);
}
```

Comment: Is there single space between numbers? and do you want to sum the numbers of each lines?

Comment: Don't use `RandomAccessFile`. Use `BufferedReader` instead. Use `readLine()` to read a line, then `split()` that on spaces, and convert each element to `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`, and add them up.

Comment: You can use `Integer.valueOf(item)` to convert the `String` into `Integer` (so that you can use addition). EDIT: Maybe `Integer.parseInt(item)` is better.

Comment: if those string are all digits you can cycle through the numbers List and sum all those number after parsing them
Integer.parseInt(String s);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly everything here works, that means your for each loop prints lines with numbers separated by space? If yes then you need to:

```java
numbers.stream().forEach(s ->
  System.out.println(Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()));
```

Getting the stream on `numbers` list, then for every line we split it by whitespaces, parse each number to Integer and then sum those numbers.

Ofcourse instead of printing you can just add it to sum list, or append to your line immediately, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can split each line using space as delimeter. Then convert to number and sum them. Assuming single space between each numbers and only integer you can do like following. When the criteria changes you can change your code accordingly

```
for(String item:numbers){
        String n[] = item.split(" ");
        for(String number: n)
            sum+= Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(sum);
        sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the data type of sum should be long

Comment: the above code is summing each line .. the numbers variable is the string of each line that you have calculated